# How to display close caption / Subtitles using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
self.player.isClosedCaptionDisplayEnabled = true
```

Above property is deprecated in iOS 11.0

New property introduce for close caption it is as below

```
self.player.appliesMediaSelectionCriteriaAutomatically = true
```

But this is not working. I am not able to see the close caption in my application. Anybody have any idea, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Apple provides an example under **Select the Desired Media Option** on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/adding_subtitles_and_alternative_audio_tracks#overview)

Comment: @Code Different  Thank you for the reply. I have tried that code but not able to see the close caption.